# Copy variable value between script tags

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I have an HTML file with two `<script>` tags. In one tag, I receive data using the `socket.io` library and process it in the other one. My code is as follows -

```
<script>
 nwmsg=[];
 var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000/');

 socket.on('message', function (data) {
   nwmsg=data.readings.slice();
   console.log('received a message: ', nwmsg[0]); // Log A
 });
</script>

<script>
 .
 .
 var temps=nwmsg.slice();
 console.log(temps[0]);     // Log B
 .
 .
</script>
```

In the scripts, I've marked the two log statements as Log A and Log B. Log A correctly prints the received data (`data.readings` is an array of JSON Objects). However, Log B shows up as `undefined` on the console.

Can anyone figure out what mistake I'm making here ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a problem of "copying" between two script tags but the issue of asynchronicity.
It take some time for socket.io to deliver the message. Basicly, you are doing log B BEFORE the message arrive to client. 
That is the reason socket.io is using callbacks to make sure that message has arrived.

So, in conclusion: If you want to access data from socket.io message, you have to do it in its callback or in function that could be executed only after this succesfull callback.

```
<script>
 nwmsg=[];
 var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000/');

 socket.on('message', function (data) {
   nwmsg=data.readings.slice();
   console.log('received a message: ', nwmsg[0]); // Log A
   nwmsgSlice();
 });
 </script>

 <script>
 .
 .
 var temps;
 function nwmsgSlice() {
   temps=nwmsg.slice();
   console.log(temps[0]);     // Log B
 }
 .
 .
</script>
```

Comment: Asynchronicity was indeed the issue. Thanks for the quick solution.